# foldLeft vs foldRight vs tailrec on Scala List

Tags: scala, performance

Assume I have a collection of `c: List[T]` sorted.

And I need to make aggregation with `foldLeft/foldRight` which outputs `(List[T],List[T],List[T])`, sorted.
To complete this, I have 2 possibilities:

1. `foldLeft`, and then reverse each one of the lists (use `::`, otherwise its `O(n)` each step)
2. `foldRight` and remain in the same order (use `::`)

I know that `foldLeft` is `tailrec` implemented and optimized, but making `O(n)` more steps to reverse the collections, in this use case - which method will generate me better performance?

Assume that the `op` is `O(1)`

Example of the code:

```
def analyzePayload(payload: JsObject, actionRules: List[ActionRule]): InspectorReport = {
    val analyzeMode = appConfig.analyzeMode
    val (succeed, notApplicable, failed) = actionRules.foldLeft((List[RuleResult](), List[RuleResult](), List[RuleResult]())) { case ( seed @ (succeed, notApplicable, failed), actionRule) =>

      // Evaluate Single ActionRule
      def step(): (List[RuleResult], List[RuleResult], List[RuleResult]) = actionRuleService.eval(actionRule, payload) match {

        // If the result is succeed
        case EvalResult(true, _, _) => (RuleResult.fromSucceed(actionRule, appConfig.showSucceedAppData) :: succeed, notApplicable, failed)

        // If the result is notApplicable
        case EvalResult(_, missing @_ :: _, _) => (succeed, RuleResult.fromNotApplicable(actionRule, appConfig.showNotApplicableAppData, missing) :: notApplicable, failed)

        // If the result is unmatched
        case EvalResult(_, _, unmatched @_ :: _) => (succeed, notApplicable, RuleResult.fromFailed(actionRule, appConfig.showFailedAppData, unmatched) :: failed)
      }

      analyzeMode match {
        case UntilFirstSucceed => if (succeed.isEmpty) step() else seed
        case UntilFirstNotApplicable => if (notApplicable.isEmpty) step() else seed
        case UntilFirstFailed => if (failed.isEmpty) step() else seed
        case Default => step()
        case _ => throw new RuntimeException(s"Unknown mode on analyzePayload with mode = ${analyzeMode}")
      }
    }

    InspectorReport(succeed.reverse, notApplicable.reverse, failed.reverse)
  }
```

---

Before that, I used `tailrec` which made **bad** preformance: (why??)

```
 def analyzePayload(payload: JsObject, actionRules: List[ActionRule]): InspectorReport = {
    val analyzeMode = appConfig.analyzeMode

    def isCompleted(succeed: Int, notApplicable: Int, failed: Int) = {
      analyzeMode match {
        case Default => false
        case UntilFirstSucceed => if (succeed == 0) false else true
        case UntilFirstNotApplicable => if (notApplicable == 0) false else true
        case UntilFirstFailed => if (failed == 0) false else true
      }
    }

    @tailrec
    def analyzePayloadRec(rules: List[ActionRule])(succeed: List[RuleResult], notApplicable: List[RuleResult], failed: List[RuleResult]): (List[RuleResult], List[RuleResult], List[RuleResult]) = {
      if (isCompleted(succeed.size, notApplicable.size, failed.size)) (succeed, notApplicable, failed)
      else rules match {

        // Base cases:
        case Nil => (succeed, notApplicable, failed)

        // Evaluate case:
        case nextRule :: tail =>
          actionRuleService.eval(nextRule, payload) match {

          // If the result is succeed
          case EvalResult(true, _, _) => analyzePayloadRec(tail)(RuleResult.fromSucceed(nextRule, appConfig.showSucceedAppData) :: succeed, notApplicable, failed)

          // If the result is notApplicable
          case EvalResult(_, missing @_ :: _, _) => analyzePayloadRec(tail)(succeed, RuleResult.fromNotApplicable(nextRule, appConfig.showNotApplicableAppData, missing) :: notApplicable, failed)

          // If the result is unmatched
          case EvalResult(_, _, unmatched @_ :: _) => analyzePayloadRec(tail)(succeed, notApplicable, RuleResult.fromFailed(nextRule, appConfig.showFailedAppData, unmatched) :: failed)
        }
      }
    }

    analyzePayloadRec(actionRules.reverse)(Nil, Nil, Nil).toInspectorReport // todo: if the analyzeModes are not Default - consider use Streams for lazy collection
  }
```

Performance:
[image]

Until 22:16, this `tailrec` analyze was in use, then, the above code.
which you can see that generates much better performance - the same data was in use.

The x-axis is `timeline` and `y-axis` is `time` in `ms` (1.4s)

Any ideas why? **tailrec** should be faster, that's why I consider using `foldRight`.

Comment: Did you try just using the span methods?

Comment: Like `partition`? or `span`? cause i don't see how its works for me in that use-case.
Also i cannot understand how the foldLeft implementation is faster than the `tailrec` code attached in the second block, i would like to know for any other suggestions that can make the performance better for me :)

Comment: Because the stdlib **List** cheats in its implementation and mutates under the hood, which allows it to be faster.

Answer (score 3):

What makes your `tailrec` version slow is

```
isCompleted(succeed.size, notApplicable.size, failed.size)
```

taking the size of a linked list in Scala is linear in the size, and you're computing the size of all three lists (at least two of which you're never using (and you don't use any of them by `Default`)).

On the `n`th iteration of the `tailrec`, you're going to walk `n` list nodes between the size computations, so `n` iterations of `tailrec` is at least `O(n^2)`.

Passing the lists themselves to `isCompleted` (as you effectively do in the `foldLeft` version) and checking `isEmpty` should dramatically speed things up (especially in the `Default` case).

Comment: Thanks @Levi Ramsey - so you think if i will change `isCompleted` to get as an input reference of 3 `lists` and use `tailrec` - does it will be faster than the same implementation with foldLeft?

Comment: There'd be a small constant savings from not building a closure.  For the cases where you go through the whole list: the performance will be basically the same (the closure difference is basically the only one in that case).  For the cases where you can stop `tailrec` early, `tailrec` will soundly beat `foldLeft`.

Comment: TL;DR: I wouldn't expect `foldLeft` to ever be faster than `tailrec` (at least not for `List`), but the "return on effort" is really a question of how often you anticipate early termination.

Comment: `tailrec` should also play nicer with JIT optimization, but whether that pays dividends is likely to vary from case to case.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have those case classes:

```
case class InspectorReport(succeed: List[ActionRule], notApplicable: List[ActionRule], failed: List[ActionRule])
case class ActionRule()
case class EvalResult(success: Boolean, missing: List[String], unmatched: List[String])
```

And the evaluator:

```
class ActionRuleService {
  def eval(actionRule: ActionRule, payload: JsObject): EvalResult = EvalResult(true, List(), List())
}

val actionRuleService = new ActionRuleService
```

I would try something like this:

```
def analyzePayload(payload: JsObject, actionRules: List[ActionRule]): InspectorReport = {
  val evaluated = actionRules.map(actionRule => (actionRule, actionRuleService.eval(actionRule, payload)))
  val (success, failed) = evaluated.partition(_._2.success)
  val (missing, unmatched) = failed.partition(_._2.missing.nonEmpty)
  InspectorReport(success.map(_._1), missing.map(_._1), unmatched.map(_._1))
}
```

Or:

```
def analyzePayload(payload: JsObject, actionRules: List[ActionRule]): InspectorReport = {
  val evaluated = actionRules.map(actionRule => (actionRule, actionRuleService.eval(actionRule, payload)))
  val success = evaluated.collect {
    case (actionRule, EvalResult(true, _, _)) =>
      actionRule
  }
  val missing = evaluated.collect {
    case (actionRule, EvalResult(false, missing, _)) if missing.nonEmpty =>
      actionRule
  }
  val unmatched = evaluated.collect {
    case (actionRule, EvalResult(false, missing, unmatched)) if missing.isEmpty && unmatched.nonEmpty =>
      actionRule
  }
  InspectorReport(success, missing, unmatched)
}
```

Comment: Thanks again @Tomer Shetah, Why thats will give better performance then foldLeft and tailrec implementation which i attached above? also the `analyzeMode` is missing here, which means `Omega(n)` will be in that case

Comment: I got the idea, thats indeed solve the `reverse` but instead of im doing 3 times `O(n)` operation on 3 collects, also its not solve the `analyzeMode` - do you think its still faster?

Comment: I am pretty sure it will be much faster. As Levi explains in his answer, you are doing `O(n^2)` in your `tailrec`. In this solution you will have `O(n)`

Comment: But if i will change the `isCompleted` to gets as an input only the list - does it will be much faster? I guess scala passing a reference

Comment: I found out that `foldLeft` is faster